# Approximation of integration of piecewise continuous function at discrete points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, approximate-integration

I have an integral of the form
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx,
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a continuous function that is not differentiable at countable number of points, defined on $[0,1]$. Suppose I take points $t_k = \frac{k-1/2}{4}, k=1,2,3,4$. Is there a way to approximate the above integral at these points? If $f$ was instead twice differentiable, then I know it can be approximated as
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx \approx \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{4} f(t_k).
\end{equation}
I am looking for similar result that will be true for continuous function which is not differentiable at countable number of points.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time where the discontinuities of $f$ are? And when you say "approximate the above integral at these points", do you mean approximate the integrand or do you mean to approximate the integral by using these values as endpoints of intervals to perform some form of numerical integration?

Comment: @QMath Yes, I do know where the discontinuities $f$ are, and I mean to approximate the integral, though not by taking the above points as endpoints of intervals, but by taking the value of the function at these points if that's possible.

Comment: @QMath I have made changes in the original question, now I am assuming $f$ is continuous, but it is not differentiable to some points.

Comment: As your function is assumed to be continuous (and therefore Riemann-integrable), I think approximating with Riemann sums would be the easiest way to do things. This involves changing your endpoints slightly. What you are doing with your approximation where you assume $f$ is twice-differentiable (which I'm not sure if this is necessary for this to apply) implicitly assumes that you are multiplying the value of a function at a point in the intervals by the length of the intervals. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann-integrable)